# (Single) Amino acid rotational degrees of freedom

Tags: bond, amino-acids

When defining the rotational degrees of freedom for a single molecule, should we just include the psi and phi angles (red lines in the picture) or the rotation around every single bond (yellow lines in the picture) or both?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be concerned with bonds where the rotation is non-trivial. For example, rotation about a C-H or O-H bond doesn't do anything. But rotation around the serine side-chain C-O bound or the side-chain central carbon bond or the C-O carboxylate bond all matter.

Comment: Thank you! So, we would say that a single serine has 4 rotational degrees of freedom (C-N, 2 * C-O, C-C)?

Comment: Are you just talking about bonds? You also have overall rotation...

Comment: Also I count a second C-C.

Comment: Thank you again; really appreciate it. I forgot the 2nd C-C. Since there are these bonds of interest, I was thinking of calculating all the possible combinations of rotations around them to get the final number, taking into account that, additionally, each of the possible non-linear "final molecules" has 3 degrees of rotational freedom.